# Eclipse plugin development - e4 part with input: instantiate input

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, e4

Eclipse 4 does not have any notion of an editor, only parts. So how do we receive the file for our "editor" parts? I'm talking about an e4 equivalent of the `IEditorPart.init` method, and the `IEditorInput` it receives.

I've stumbled upon [this example](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/e4/org.eclipse.e4.ui/+/integration/examples?autodive=0%2F%2F)  by Tom Schindl. He is able to inject the input in the part constructor. For the input object to be available for injection, it has to be instantiated in the `IEclipseContext` somehow. [This article](http://modelmoo.blogspot.no/2013/04/eclipse-modeling-framework-ui-e4.html) refers to Schindl's example, and leads me to consider the following approach: intercept "Open file" commands (if they exist) from the Eclipse platform, create an input instance for the "editor" part and put it in the context (`IEcpliseContext.set(class, value)`), and open the part with the `EPartService`.

So the question is: is this the right approach to creating an e4 "editor"? And is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to put the input data in the part's transient data since it is tricky to get the data injected at the right point.

For something that behaves like an editor you will probably use a Part Descriptor so that you can create multiple parts from the single descriptor.

You would create the part using something like:

```java
@Inject
EPartService partService;

// Create from part descriptor

MPart part = partService.createPart("part descriptor id");

// Set input in transient data

part.getTransientData().put("inputKey", inputData);

// Add to part stack 

MPartStack partStack = ... stack you want to use

partStack.getChildren().add(part);

// Show

partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

In your part code you get the transient data by injecting the `MPart`. For example in the constructur:

```java
@Inject
public MyClass(MPart myPart)
{
  Object input = part.getTransientData().get("inputKey");

  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How do we access the transient data from inside the part then? And where exactly can I put your proposed code? I want to open the part as a response to opening a file with the relevant file extension.

Comment: Added the code to access the transient data in the part.

Comment: I see, thanks. Feels weird injecting a part into a part!

But, for the second part of my question: since in e4 the editor extension point is not used, how can we associate the part to a file extension, and make sure it gets opened?

Comment: In a pure e4 application there is no file system support. You can use the content type system in `org.eclipse.core.contenttypes` but it is up to you to match that up to files. This is really a separate question.